# Convert pandas series of dictionary to numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, series

The following series contains a string of dictionaries of key values. Split the list into columns a and column b in such a way that column a and column b will be 0 if the list is empty else, 1.

## Input:

```
list = ["{'a': [], 'b': []}",
        "{'a': [{'c':3,'d':56}], 'b': []}",
        "{'a': [], 'b': [{'c':45,'d':67}]}",
        "{'a': [{'c':48,'d':676}], 'b': [{'c':29,'d':90}]}" ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=list,columns=['A'])
```

Output:

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another version:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

lst = [
    "{'a': [], 'b': []}",
    "{'a': [{'c':3,'d':56}], 'b': []}",
    "{'a': [], 'b': [{'c':45,'d':67}]}",
    "{'a': [{'c':48,'d':676}], 'b': [{'c':29,'d':90}]}",
]


df = pd.DataFrame(literal_eval(v) for v in lst)
df = df.applymap(bool).astype(int)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   a  b
0  0  0
1  1  0
2  0  1
3  1  1
```

Comment: List is column of df. Process based on df column.

Comment: change `lst` to `df.A`

Comment: ValueError: malformed node or string is getting.

Answer (score 2):

Similar solution like @Andrej Kesely answer - only removed converting to lists and double [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.A.tolist()).astype(bool).astype(int)
print (df)
   a  b
0  0  0
1  1  0
2  0  1
3  1  1
```

Comment: Updated question. df['A'] to split into df['a'] and df['b']